# Delete all the resources but not the resource group using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

There is an [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63744842/azure-cli-delete-resource-without-deleting-resource-group) in the Stack overflow that contains the commands for deleting the resources in a resource group but it's not working for us.

In the Azure Cloud Shell,
When using the command given from above link, getting the error as:

`unrecognized arguments: ConvertFron-Json Foreach-Object {az resource delete --ids /usr/bin/cloudshellhelp.id --verbose`

for the command: `az resource list --resource-group senthil-b-rg ConvertFrom-Json Foreach-Object {az resource delete --resource-group senthil-b-rg --ids $_.id --verbose}`

If I keep pipe (|) symbol in the command:

```
az resource list --resource-group senthil-b-rg \
| ConvertFrom-Json | Foreach-Object {az resource delete --resource-group senthil-b-rg --ids $_.id --verbose}
```

Errors are

```
bash:ConvertFrom-Json: command not found
bash: Foreach-Object: command not found
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipleError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: You’re mixing PowerShell and CLI commands.

Comment: Oh, I'm new to CLI & PowerShell! Could you give me some hint on how to resolve this @GauravMantri

Comment: Using azoure cloud shell, you could choose bash or powershell, if you select powershell it should work.

Comment: `Content: {"Code":"Conflict","Message":"Server farm 'webappserviceplan' cannot be deleted because it has web app(s) azjavawebapp assigned to it.` `Some resources failed to be deleted` - Got this message while running the command in Azure Cloud Shell (PowerShell) but all the resources inside the resource group were deleted!

Comment: To avoid this conflict message, do we need to delete the resources using order like 1st web app, next is app service plan as given in the same [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63745410/19615125)?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

```bash
az resource list --resource-group myresourcegroup \
| ConvertFrom-Json | Foreach-Object {az resource delete --resource-group myresourcegroup --ids $_.id --verbose}
```

**Response:**

[image]

In my resource group, I have **resources** like below:

[image]

***To resolve the error, I tried to run the same command in PowerShell and got the same warning as below:***

[image]

But the resources got deleted in the Portal:

[image]

Please **note** that, while deleting the resources you need to follow the order:

- Make sure to delete the **child** (nested) resources initially.
- Delete the resources that manage the other resources.

**Reference:**

[Delete resource group and resources - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/delete-resource-group?tabs=azure-powershell#how-order-of-deletion-is-determined)

**UPDATE:**

To get rid of the warning, you need to add **`--only-show-errors`** in the command like below:

```
$resources = az resource list --resource-group myresourcegroup | ConvertFrom-Json  
foreach ($resource in $resources) {  
az resource delete --resource-group myresourcegroup --ids $resource.id --only-show-errors  
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Make sure to remove **--verbose** as **`--only-show-errors`** doesn't work with it.

Comment: Resources were deleted but What is that cmdlet used to get rid of conflict error message?

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/E23rELR.png - Still getting the same conflict message but resources are deleting.

Comment: Please check the CLI version you are using and update it to latest version.